# submitting app to apple

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

i have a question regarding submitting app to apple. I have my program written and tested on actual devices. I have a certificate and provision profile set up so i can load it unto my device. However, when i go on the apple official web site to see the steps that i need to take before submitting, it requires me to get a certificate and provisoin profile again? So what do i do? Do i delete my old provisioning profile or what do i do? Confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to delete your Developer certificate or mobile-provisions. You do need to request and download a Distribution certificate and a distribution profile before building a submittable app.

Answer (score 0):

The process is kind of confusing at first, but after some time you get used to it:

For distributing the app, you have to have a distribution certificate.
Do not delete your developing certificate. Leave it there ;)
after downbloading and installing the certificate on your Xcode (on organizer), change the signing identity from your project settings (if you have XCode 4, on the navigation menu click on your project main item, then go to build settings and change the signing identity for your project to the distribution profile).
After that you will be able to archive your application (on the product menu from your Xcode).
After archiving, you can test the build and upload it to apple from your Organizer Window...
Hope to have helped!
Best of luck...

Comment: hi, thx for your answer, right now i have two objects(same name) under my product menu. I am confused to why there are two...